# Infinite Product $\prod_n^\infty \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^s}} \rightarrow$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Can this $$P_n(s)=\prod_{m=2}^n \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{m^s}}$$ for s>1 and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}$ be written any simpler (does it converge)? When $m$ runs here only over the primes this is the famous Euler-Product form of the Riemann zeta function.

Is there anything known for this product when n runs over all natural numbers? For checking the convergence one could look at

$$\log P_m(s) = -\sum_{m=2}^n \log(1-\frac{1}{m^s})$$

and use the integral criterion. I somehow did not succeed to integrate it.

(The idea how I came up with this was somehow to write the zeta function as quotient of this function and a similiar one with terms from the Erathostenes sieve:
$$ \zeta(s) = \frac{P(s)}{\prod_{m,n=1}^\infty \left[ 1-((m+1)(n+1))^{-s}\right]^{-\frac{1}{M(m,n)}}}.$$

Here $M(n,m)$ is [obviously](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778501/how-often-yields-l1m1-for-l-m-in-1-one-and-the-same-number) the number of divisors $\sigma_0$ of $nm$ minus two:
$$M(n,m)=\sigma_0(mn) -2,$$
using the prime factorisation of $nm=\prod_{i}p_i^{\alpha_i}$ it is in turn
$$\sigma_0(nm)=\prod_i (\alpha_i + 1).$$
)

Comment: PS: Are you sure you want to begin your summation at $m=1$?

Comment: It does converge for $s>1$ provided you omit the term with $m=1$ in the infinite product. Use the basic theorem:  If  $0\leq x_n<1$ for $n\in N$ then $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-x_n)>0$  $\iff \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n<\infty.$   Another basic theorem is that if $0\leq x_n$  for $n\in N$ then $\prod_{n\in N}(1+x_n)<\infty$  $\iff \sum_{n\in N}x_n<\infty.$

Comment: so you know that when $x \to 0$ : $\ln(1+x) \sim x$ which means indeed  that $|\ln(1+x)| < |x| (1+\epsilon)$ when $|x|$ is small enough. hence showing that $\sum_m \log(1-m^{-s})$ converges reduces to showing that $\sum_m |m^{-s}|$ converges

Comment: and for the (non) convergence on $Re(s) = 1$, you'll need to write that $\ln(1+x) - x \sim -x^2$ when $x \to 0$, hence $\sum_m \log(1-m^{-s}) + m^{-s}$ converges on $Re(s) = 1$, and since $\sum_m m^{-s}$ diverges, you get that $\sum_m \ln(1-m^{-s})$ diverges

Comment: and "to write the zeta function as quotient of this function and a similiar one" you mean write $\zeta(s)$ as the $\log$ of the quotient of this function and a similar one

Comment: No I mean actually something in the sense of $\zeta=\frac{P}{\prod_{m,n}(1-((n+1)(m+1))^{-s})}$

Comment: since $\displaystyle\zeta(s) = \prod_{p\in \mathcal{P}} (1-p^{-s})^{-1}$, it is obvious that with $\displaystyle F(s) = \prod_{m \ge 2} (1-m^{-s})^{-1}$ you get $$\zeta(s) = \frac{F(s)}{\prod_{m \ge 2, m \not \in \mathcal{P}} (1-m^{-s})^{-1}}$$ but it is of no interest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments since $\sum \frac{1}{n^k}$ converges for $k>1$ so does the product. I will here derive a formula for $P(k)$ that is valid for integers $k>1$. We start by factoring 
$$\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n^k}} = \frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}}{n}\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi i(k-1)}{k}}}{n}\right)} =  \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(1+\frac{z_k^i}{n}\right)^{-1}$$ where $z_k = -e^{\frac{2\pi i}{k}}$. Changing the order of the products gives us

$$P_N(k) = (-1)^{k+1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{e^{-\gamma z_i}}{z_i}\prod_{n=2}^N\left(1+\frac{z_k^i}{n}\right)^{-1}e^{\frac{z_i}{n}}$$
where we have used $z_0z_1\cdots z_{k-1}=(-1)^{k+1}$ and $z_0+z_1+\ldots+z_{k-1} = 0$ which implies $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}e^{-\gamma z_i} = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}e^{\frac{z_i}{n}} = 1$ and $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}z_j = (-1)^{(k+1)}$.

These terms have been inserted for the next step which is to use the [Weierstrass product formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#19th_century:_Gauss.2C_Weierstrass_and_Legendre) for $\Gamma(z)$ which allows us to write
$$P_N(k) = (-1)^{k+1}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\Gamma_N(z_i)(1+z_i)$$

where $\lim_{N\to\infty}\Gamma_N(z) = \Gamma(z)$. Since $\lim_{z\to -1}\Gamma(z)(1+z) = 1$ the $i=0$ term does not contibute to the product (the treatement of the $i=0$ term should be done more carefully above; but the naive treatement here works) and by taking $N\to\infty$ and using $\Gamma(2+z_i)=(1+z_i)z_i\Gamma(z_i)$ we obtain

$$P(k) = \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\Gamma(2+z_i) = \prod_{j=1}^{k-1}\Gamma\left(2 - e^{\frac{2\pi i j}{k}}\right)$$

In particular this gives the values

$$P(2) = 2,~~~P(3) = \frac{3\pi}{\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)},~~~P(4) = \frac{4\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}$$

and as $k\to\infty$ we have the approximation $P(k) \simeq 1 + \frac{1}{2^k}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that $1-\frac1x = \frac{x-1}{x}$. Then you can simplify

$$\begin{align*}\log P_m(s) &= -\sum_n \log(1-\frac{1}{m^s}) \\
&= -\sum \log(\frac{m^s-1}{m^s}) \\
&= \sum\log(m^s)-\log(m^s-1) \end{align*}$$

Comment: Yes I know, but that didn't help (me) too much with the integration.

Comment: I do not think you can express the integral as an elementrary function, however you could find an antiderivative in terms of [polylogarithmic functions.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Polylogarithm.html)

Comment: Mathematica got me -(x*(s*Hypergeometric2F1[1, s^(-1), 1 + s^(-1), x^s] - Log[x^s] + Log[-1 + x^s])), whatever that might mean in this case.

Comment: it is a not simplification nor an answer.. if you know how to compute $\sum_{m < N} \log(m^s-1)$ then you know how to compute $\sum_{m < N} \log(1-m^{-s})$, it is just obvious

Comment: @Franky_GTH Plugging it into wolframalpha you get [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+log%28m^x%29-log%28m^x-1%29)