# How many times is $n=(l+1)(m+1)$ generated while progressing through $l,m \in \{1,...\}$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

The sequence $n = (l+1)(m+1)$ for $l,m \in \{1,...\}$ yields exactly all non-prime (compound) numbers $n$. In general each non-prime number in this way is yielded $M(n)$ times. What is $M(n)$?

I came up with this question due to [that here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1777129/infinite-product-prod-n-infty-frac11-frac1ns-rightarrow).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the number 30. Its prime factorization it $30 = 2\times 3\times 5$. Then your equation predicts that it will show up
$
M(30) = 2^{3-1} \times (1 \times 1 \times 1) = 4
$
times, but it actually shows up 6 times, when $(l+1,m+1) = (2,15)$, $(3,10)$, $(5,6)$, $(6,5)$, $(10,3)$ and $(15,2)$.

We *can* determine $M(n)$ though. Let
$$
n = p_1^{\alpha_1} \cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}.
$$
Then the number of divisors of $n$ is 
$$
\sigma(n) = \prod_{i=1}^m (\alpha_i + 1).
$$
This comes from the fact that any divisor $d$ of $n$ will have the form
$d = p_1^{\beta_1} \cdots p_m^{\beta_m}$ where $0 \leq \beta_i \leq \alpha_i$, and so there are $\alpha_i + 1$ options for $\beta_i$, giving us the expression above. For any $n$, let $d_1, \ldots, d_{\sigma(n)}$ be the divisors. Then the values $(l+1,m+1)$ giving $n$ are $(d_1, n/d_1), \ldots, (d_{\sigma(n)}, n/d_{\sigma(n)})$, giving $\sigma(n)$ tuples. But this list includes the points $(1,n)$ and $(n,1)$, which clearly aren't allowed, so we simply subtract 2 to account for this. This gives us
$$
M(n) = \sigma(n) - 2 = \prod_{i=1}^m (\alpha_i + 1) - 2.
$$

Comment: The number of divisors, yes that seems right! But should it be $M(24)$ or $M(30)$?

Comment: Oh whoops, yeah I meant M(30), I don't know why I wrote M(24). My bad! Should be fixed now.